# Custom AbstractCursor with json content

Tags: android, json, cursor

Is it possible to use the cursor class to expose a json object? 
I have a custom abstract cursor(param = json object) and find I can't override the abstract cursor moveToFirst/moveToNext to support iteration. 
Any pointers on how to keep the json format(no probs  parsing the json) within the cursor without transforming it, would be great.

Thanks Alex

Comment: Is the JSON data in a single String?  Is it a byte stream?

Comment: "Is it possible to use the cursor class to expose a json object?"  Is it really a JSON object?  Or is it a JSON array?  What's the cursor supposed to do when it iterates?  Move to the next token? the next element name/value pair?  What if the next element value is a complex object or array?  I can't figure out how this approach to handling JSON is desirable (or how it's supposed to work).  What problem does it solve that's not more easily solved by just transforming the JSON into a Java data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MatrixCursor to return data that you have either in xml or json format.

[MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html) : A mutable cursor implementation backed by an array of Objects.

```
final MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(SEARCH_COLUMN_NAMES);              
for (OpenSearchHandler.Result result : results) {                       
     cursor.addRow(new Object[] { result.id, result.title, result.description, result.url });
}
```